# How can I limit the columns that are seen in a table created with Treeview?

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Let's see, let me explain, in the program everything works fine, the data appears, the columns that are 8, I put 2 scrollbars, one vertical and the other horizontal, these work correctly. But, the table having so many columns extends too much covering more than I want in the window. I would like to know if there is any way to limit the visible columns, or control the width of the Treeview.

this is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

window = Tk()
window.resizable(1,1)
width = 1350
height= 500
window.geometry(f"{width}x{height}")

tree = ttk.Treeview(window,height=3,columns=("#1","#2","#3","#4","#5","#6")) #define how many 
columns the table will have
tree.place(x=10,y=20) # position

# title the columns
tree.heading("#0",text= "CODE",anchor= "center")
tree.heading("#1",text= "PRODUCT",anchor= "center")
tree.heading("#2",text= "PROVIDER",anchor= "center")
tree.heading("#3",text= "KIND",anchor= "center")
tree.heading("#4",text= "PRICE",anchor= "center")
tree.heading("#5",text= "QUANTITY",anchor= "center")
tree.heading("#6",text= "DESCRIPTION",anchor= "center")

# se configura cada columna
tree.column("#0", minwidth=100, width=150, stretch= False)
tree.column("#1", minwidth=150, width=200, stretch= False)
tree.column("#2", minwidth=150, width=200, stretch= False)
tree.column("#3", minwidth=150, width=200, stretch= False)
tree.column("#4", minwidth=100, width=150, stretch= False)
tree.column("#5", minwidth=100, width=150, stretch= False)
tree.column("#6", minwidth=300, width=300, stretch= False)

# define the vertical scrollbar
scroll_databaseV = Scrollbar(window, orient="vertical", command=tree.yview)
scroll_databaseV.place(x=10, y=20, height=100)
tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_databaseV.set)

#define the horizontal scrollbar
scroll_databaseH = Scrollbar(window, orient="horizontal", command=tree.xview)
scroll_databaseH.place(x=10, y=107, width=700)
tree.configure(xscrollcommand=scroll_databaseH.set)

# enter the data in the treeview
tree.insert("", END, text="CODE001", values=("PRODUCT1", "PROVIDER1", "KIND1", 200, 100, "DESCRIPTION"))
tree.insert("", END, text="CODE002", values=("PRODUCT2", "PROVIDER2", "KIND2", 200, 100, "DESCRIPTION"))
tree.insert("", END, text="CODE003", values=("PRODUCT3", "PROVIDER3", "KIND3", 200, 100, "DESCRIPTION"))
tree.insert("", END, text="CODE004", values=("PRODUCT4", "PROVIDER4", "KIND4", 200, 100, "DESCRIPTION"))
tree.insert("", END, text="CODE005", values=("PRODUCT5", "PROVIDER5", "KIND5", 200, 100, "DESCRIPTION"))

window.mainloop()
```

[image]

As you can see in the image, I would like the Treeview to only reach the end of the scrollbar that is in horizontal position. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the `.place` geometry manager.

It has a parameter called `width`. You can set that equal to 700, which is the size of your horizontal scroll bar

```
tree = ttk.Treeview(window,height=3,columns=("#1","#2","#3","#4","#5","#6")) #define how many 
tree.place(x=10,y=20,width=700) # position
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Welcome, please accept and upvote the answer of it solves the problem @Paiblou